# NSMutableArray lastObject not working in UITableView iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I want to get the last object from an `NSMutableArray`. When I use the code below to get the last object from the `NSMutableArray` it is not finding it:

```
if ([mutableArray lastObject])
{
  NSLog(@"Last Object");
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"Not a Last Object");
}
```

When ever I call this code the `if` statement is only calling for every objects from an array. Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Comment: @Monolo Thanks for your help. I have solve the issue from Mr.Moxy's answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mutableArray lastObject] returns an id typed object which is the last object of your array. it is not a test.

To see it you should write something like :

```
id myLastObject = [mutableArray lastObject];
NSLog(@"my last object is : %@",myLastObject);
```

edit :
What do you mean by check last object ?

checking equality with the isEqual method checks if both objects are same objects, meaning only one object but you might wanna check if two objects have same properties, thus checking if properties have same values.

Comment: I want to check last object. I can get the last object using your code. Can you please tell me how to check the NSMutableArray? Thanks in advance.

Comment: He answered you correctly. You wil have to explain what do you want to check? If it is empty?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([someObject isEqual:[mutableArray lastObject]]) {

      NSLog(@"Last Object");

}
```